# config can't find libgtk2

Tags: gtk-2

I tried installing PCSXR from codeplex, since the software center version won't work for me. When I used the `./configure` command, it eventually showed an error when searching for GTK2:

```
checking for GTK2... no
configure: error: *** libgtk2 not found!
```

But when I looked in the Synaptic Package Manager, it showed I did have the libgtk2 files. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the headers, contained in the -dev package.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libgtk2.0-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

You may need additional packages, check the dependency list, and install the relevant -dev packages (or sort it out one error at a time, lol)

Comment: Thanks! I already had that package, but using this command solved the problem either way. I'll try to install the other packages myself!